# How can I bypass Textmate asking for my password every time I save a file?

Tags: textmate, macos

I'm using Lion and every time I edit a file, TextMate prompt me for my password.

Is there a way to bypass that?

Comment: Hi there. I voted to move this to www.superuser.com since it is more of a general computer question than a programming question. You should get much better answers over there. Cheers!

Comment: I reworded your question so that it's not the same thing as the question. I added (and assumed) that you're trying to edit system files, if that is not correct, please edit the question to remove that part.

Comment: So you're being prompted for a password every time you try to edit any file in TextMate? Does this happen if you use another program to edit the files (like, for instance, TextEdit)?

Comment: yeah same thing happens, but this time i got it to work :p, chmod ugo+w * everything in the project, thanks for the push :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `chmod -R ug+w project-dir` (starting from the root of the project)

Comment: This leaves all files world-writable which might be dangerous -> isn't `chmod -R u+w` enough?

Comment: you're right, it's dangerous, seems that I need at least chmod -R ug+w access though to not get textmate to ask for my pw, thanks!

Comment: "world"-writable, for the world of people who have an account on your machine. Could be dangerous in some contexts, but...

Answer (score 2):

Chances are you are trying to save your file somewhere other than under your home directory.  In my experience, Textmate `Save` dialogs often default to the system root directory.  If you try to save there, you will get an authentication request as you normally would not have write permission.  Expand the `Save` dialog box and choose somewhere in your home directory tree.

Comment: I don't think I'm saving in my home directory. I'm saving in "/users/myusername/rails_projects".

Comment: @WaleyChen `/Users/MyUsername/` is equal to `~` your home directory, everything below it, ie. `rails_projects` should have permissions set to you, if not, you can change it with `chown username filename`

Comment: Still getting blanks. I used chown and chmoded everything on the file hello.txt "-rwxrwxrwx   1 nikeelevet  staff    3 19 Oct 23:01 hello.txt" but TextMate still opens a blank file. I think this might be a tricky problem ...